# Bind ViewModel from main flavor to overridden one in another flavor with Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel, android-productflavors

**What I have** 
A project with one flavor except the main one. 
In the main flavor I have `MyFragment` and `MyViewModel`. 
`MyFragment` takes the half of the screen and is displayed in another fragment which is just a container.

View model injection happens the following way:

```
class Fragment: Fragment() {
  @Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
  private val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel> { viewModelFactory }
}
```

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
  private val viewModels: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
  override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}
```

In the second flavor I have `MyFlavoredFragment` which is displayed under `MyFragment`, in the same container fragment, and takes the other half of the screen. 
In this fragment I need the already existed view model from `MyFragment`, so I try to get it by the following way:

```
class FlavoredFragment: Fragment() {
  @Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
  private val viewModel: MyFlavoredViewModel by viewModels(
    ownerProducer = {
      requireParentFragment()
        .childFragmentManager
        .findFragmentByTag(MyFragment.TAG)!!
    },
    factoryProducer = {
      viewModelFactory
    }
  )
}
```

**What I want** 
Not changing anything in `MainFragment` I want it starts using `MyFlavoredViewModel` over declared `MyViewModel`. 
As well, I want the injected view model in `MyFlavoredFragment` be the exact same instance already created in `MyFragment`.

But it does not work as expected. When `MyFlavoredFragment` gets displayed, a new instance of `MyFlavoredViewModel` gets created.
In `MyFragment` the correct type `MyFlavoredViewModel` gets created over declared `MyViewModel`, though.

My dagger setup is:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
  modules = [
    MyModule::class
  ]
)
interface AppComponent {
  fun inject(myFragment: MyFragment)
}

@Singleton
@Component(
  modules = [
    MyFlavoredModule::class
  ]
)
interface FlavoredAppComponent : AppComponent {
  override fun inject(myFragment: MyFragment)
  fun inject(flavoredFragment: FlavoredFragment)
}

@Module
abstract class MyModule {
  @Binds
  abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ViewModelKey(MyViewModel::class)
  abstract fun myViewModel(myViewModel: MyViewModel): ViewModel
}
@Module
abstract class MyFlavoredModule {
  @Binds
  abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ViewModelKey(MyViewModel::class)
  abstract fun myViewModel(myFlavoredViewModel: MyFlavoredViewModel): ViewModel

  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ViewModelKey(MyFlavoredViewModel::class)
  abstract fun myFlavoredViewModel(myFlavoredViewModel: MyFlavoredViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

I have also tried a solution with `@Repeatable ViewModelKey`, that didn't work either. 
Is this even possible what I want to achieve?

Comment: Btw, it has been successfully achieved with Koin 2.1.6 [here](https://github.com/ivan8m8/KoinViewModelBug/tree/koin-2.1.6).

Comment: Have you looked into `by activityViewModels`?

Comment: @TheLibrarian Yes. I don't want to scope the view model to the `Activity`, though.

Comment: Why not? Don't take me wrong, I am not saying that it is something wrong to do but there is no standard way to do it and rather than finding hacky solution to that I would rather ask what are the issues that prevent you to use it.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Because I use the single Activity approach, so I do not need the view model lives nearly the whole app time. And yeah, that comes up to my mind after 2 days of trying, that there's no _right_ way to achieve that with Dagger. Btw, that has been pretty easy achieved with Koin 2.1.6 without any hacks, at all.

Comment: Do you use navigation component?

Comment: @TheLibrarian no